# VAE loss Function using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

I have a task to implement loss functions of provided formulas using methods from Keras library. 
The the formulas are:[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Hs2.png)

And I need to provide implementation here:

```
def vae_loss_function(x, x_pred, mu, sigma, kl_weight=0.0005):
  latent_loss = ...
  reconstruction_loss = ...
  vae_loss = ...
  return vae_loss
```

I was trying to find out which method I should use but I can't find similar example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keras backend to implement the functions.

Here is an implementation which I used to code the `vae_loss`

ref: https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/

```
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mse
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
def vae_loss_function(x, x_pred, mu, sigma, kl_weight=0.0005):
  latent_loss =  0.5*(sigma + K.square(mu) - 1 - K.exp(sigma))
  reconstruction_loss = mse(x, x_pred)
  vae_loss = kl_weights*latent_loss + reconstruction_loss
  return vae_loss
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm totally noob if we talk about python and all this machine learning staff, but I must make it done :P

Comment: Cna you explain me one more thing ? Why don't we include this summation operator in our code ?

Comment: Because, we are using vectorized form of code with tensors, we don't need loops.